# Custom Header Cell Template of UI-GRID not working in FireFox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using http://ui-grid.info/ and trying to define a custom headerCellTemplate in columnDefs.
When i attach the code directly in controller against column it works, but I want it in a separate HTML file and want to load from there.
In separate file it works in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla Fire Fox.

Ui grid config are

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        displayName: 'Delete',
        field: deleteField,
        enableSorting: false,
        enableColumnResizing: false,
        headerCellClass: 'text-center vertical-align-middle',
        headerCellTemplate: 'deleteHeaderCellTemplate.html',
        cellTemplate: 'deleteCellTemplate.html',
    }
]
```

In deleteHeaderCellTemplate.html my code is

```
<button type="button"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
    ng-class="{'disabled': grid.appScope.isDisabled()}"
    ng-click="grid.appScope.DeleteRecord()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> {{col.displayName}}
```

It works in chrome but it does not works in Mozilla firefox

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.